# split a list of sublist based on their first elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

if i have a list that looks something like (list a)

```
my_list=[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 0]]
```

i want to split that list into something like this (list b)

```
my_list = [ [[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]] , [[4, 1], [4, 0]] ]
```

as you can see, list b is sorted and grouped together by the values of the first element of the sublists. The order of the pairs doesn't change.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.groupby(...)` should do the trick:

```py
import itertools

my_list=[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 0]]
#although your input seems to be sorted by 1st element I'll put it in here, in case if it wouldn't be
my_list=sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])

my_list=list(list(el) for k, el in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Output:

```py
[[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 0]]]
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group on the first element:

```
my_list = itertools.groupby(my_list, key = lambda e: e[0])
```

This will give you an `itertools.groupby` generator object of (key, list) pairs. Ignore the keys and convert it into a list by doing

```
[list(e[1]) for e in my_list]
```

This gives:

```
[[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 1], [4, 0]]
new_list =[]

j =0
for i in list(set([ value[0] for value in my_list])) :
    temp_list = []
    while (j < len(my_list)) and (my_list[j][0] == i):
        temp_list.append(my_list[j])
        j=j+1
    new_list.append(temp_list)


print (new_list)
```

[[[3, 1], [3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 0]]]